# how to change variables in a while-loop used outside the loop in java

Tags: java, loops, variables

```
(...)
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
System.out.println(x);

while ( y == 1)
{
 x = 2;
 y = y + 1;
}
```

How can I change afterwards the x of the System.out.println?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I wrote it very easy but I want to change the x in the while loop and use it at the beginning

Comment: How do you plan to use the value of an assignment that hasn't occurred yet?

Comment: I dont understand your question. I need to change a number that has been written out at the beginning of the programm.

Comment: Do you want to see the whole program?

Comment: No, I don't want the whole program. I want you to explain the behavior you want. If `x` was written out when its value was `1`, then that's final. If you change `x` later, that won't affect what was printed previously.

Comment: You can't change the value of x once it's been printed. If you want to print the new value, you put the println after the while loop, or inside if you want it printed each loop.

Comment: So which options do i have to output a value and change it afterwards without having it at the end of the whole output.

Comment: @FazeMala You could ask a question on SO asking how to do that, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wrote it very easy but I want to change the x in the while loop and use it at the beginning

You can't. You have to move the `System.out.println` line to *after* the while loop to use the newly calculated value.

Comment: But if i want for example a variable counting the while loop at the beginning of the program? what schould i do?

Comment: It sounds like you want to update the text in the terminal, not just output additional lines. There are special control characters interpreted by the terminal that can do that.

Comment: Yes exactly that is what I want to do. Which are these special control characters?

Comment: Is it the same for mac?